# How to set the value of an option when using ng-options in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting customer for given id,Customer details are name, email and type of customer {0,1}. **For 0, customer will be Regular and 1 will Temporary.**

I am able to show details of customer on form but but able to select the type of customer. My select options are showing {'regular', 'temporary'}, but not select any option value.

For example

```
customer1={'name':'john', 'email':'john@gmail.com', 'customer_type':0}
```

Form is able to show name and email but not selecting **'regular'** options

**Controller**

```
   $scope.customers_type=['regular','temporary'];
   //I will get details of customer
   $scope.customer=getCustomer($scope.id);

   if($scope.customer.customer_type ==0)
      $scope.customer.type=$scope.customers_type[0]     
    else
      $scope.customer.type=$scope.customers_type[1]
```

**HTML**

```
 <div>
     <label for="Name">Name </label>
     <input  ng-model='customer.name' name="Name" type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
     <label for="email">Email </label>
     <input  ng-model='customer.email' name="email" type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
     <label for="enterprise">Type of type of Customer </label>
     <select ng-model='customer.type'  type="text"  ng-options="type for type in customers_type">
     </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: you *are already* getting the value of the option; perhaps what you are asking is how to get the `index` of the item?  i.e. right now, `customer.type` can equal the *values* `'regular'` or `'temporary'`, but your model has `0` and `1`.

Comment: @Claies, yes you are right..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is working fine without any error for `angularjs 1.2.23`

Just have replaced `getCustomer` method to object.

If it is not working then **Check customer object** using breakpoint and check whether it's proper or not and also check which version of `angularjs` you are using.

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller('MyContrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.customers_type = ['regular', 'temporary'];
  //I will get details of customer
  $scope.customer = {
    'name': 'john',
    'email': 'john@gmail.com',
    'customer_type': 0
  };

  if ($scope.customer.customer_type === 0) {
    $scope.customer.type = $scope.customers_type[0]
  } else {
    $scope.customer.type = $scope.customers_type[1]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyContrl">
  <div>
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <input ng-model='customer.name' name="Name" type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input ng-model='customer.email' name="email" type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="enterprise">Type of type of Customer</label>
    <select ng-model='customer.type' type="text" ng-options="type for type in customers_type">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify `ng-selected` and set it to your current customer type.
If you don't specify `ng-selected` you'll end up with 3 options: '', 'regular', 'temporary'